# 2013 Honda Accord clicking repeatedly on its own?

Tags: honda, battery, starting, accord

I come home at 2:30 today.  Two hours later, I go out to the garage to find my car clicking repeatedly while the parking lights flicker in unison with the clicks.  I hadn't even gotten into my car yet.  It was doing this all by itself.  The sound appears to be coming from a fuse box beneath the hood.  I have keyless entry and cannot start my car.

I will note that my oil light came on last week and also, at around the same time, the battery light for my fob.  This seems battery-related, but I can't imagine either of those would make my car come alive on its own like this.  A couple times in the past, I have pressed the ignition button to have it turn over and grind a few times before it actually started (akin to turning the key and having to hold it for a few seconds before the car starts).

Comment: You should really start with changing your fob battery. But did you say your oil light came on last week? It's probably unrelated, but I assume you fixed that asap?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen electronic toys with very weak batteries do what you're describing.  They try to come on, but as everything starts to power up, the little remaining battery current can't keep up, and the toy goes dark, just to start the process over again.

If your battery is very weak, I could see how the key less entry system might be starting to "boot up" and blink the lights, but the current draw from all the lights (which is significant) is too much for the battery, so it dies.  The low power electronics then try to start again only to be starved when the lights try to fire, and so on.

Check the battery voltage now.  It should be close to 12v, but I suspect it will be much lower.  Then try to get a jump start.  If the car starts, check the voltage when the car is running.  It should be closer to 14v if the alternator is charging properly.

And as far as the oil light - you checked the oil level right?